# How to enable case sensitivity in checking the file name in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I would like to check the file existence using shell script. I used below code.
If I have TEST.png or test.png, for both the file names if condition is succeeding and printing File found. But I would like to enable case sensitivity for file check. Please let me know how to enable case sensitivity in shell script.

```
    file="/mnt/floppy/test.png"
    if [ -f "$file" ]
    then
         echo "File found"

    else
         echo "Invalid file" 
    fi
```

Comment: Shell/bash is actually case sensitive per default

Comment: Judging by the file path you're trying to check, you're dealing with the case insensitive filesystem, probably VFAT.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at VFAT's case sensitivity mount options:

> `check=s`: strict, case sensitive
>
> `check=r`: relaxed, case insensitive
>
> `check=n`: normal, default setting, currently case insensitive

---

Source: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/vfat.txt

Answer (score -1):

You can use grep:

```
file="/mnt/floppy/test.png"
echo $file | grep [A-Z] && echo "Invalid file: Filename has uppercase letters" && exit 1
# echo file | grep [a-z] && echo "Valid file"
```

Comment: Also (since someone is bound to mention this) you can use the POSIX character classes `[[:upper:]]` and `[[:lower:]]` instead of `[A-Z]` and `[a-z]`.

Comment: You can do this entirely in the shell; `case $file in *[A-Z]*) echo Uppercase;; esac` -- but the question seems to be about finding whether a file exists, regardless of case variations in the file name in the variable, which is a rather harder problem.